# Connecting Oracle to R issue

Tags: r, oracle, rstudio, roracle

I am trying to connect Oracle to RStudio using the "ROracle" package. I've installed the package and loaded it. I also have the "DBI" package installed and loaded.

I am using `dbConnect(dbDriver("Oracledrivername"),oracle_schema,oracle_password,dbname="dbname")` to connect to my oracle schema but I am getting this error:

Error in h(simpleError(msg,call)):
eror in evaluating the argument 'drv' in selecting a method for function 'dbConnect'

I then tried to narrow it down by testing `dbDriver("Oracledrivername")` by itself and the Error I get is:
Error: Couldn't find driver Oracledrivername

Things that I have done to attempt to fix this are:

- I tested my connection to "Oracledrivername" in the ODBC data source administrator, the connection was ok.
- The Rstudio I am using is 64 bit, Oracle client is a v12.1.0 64 bit, and the ODBC driver was set up on 64 bit
- I have set the oracle_home location to C:\ORACLE12_64BIT\product\12.1.0\client_1

Comment: Does https://db.rstudio.com/databases/oracle/ help?

Comment: I ended up downloading a more recent version of oracle client which did the trick